# Как использовать ViewModel c Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

Перехожу на иcпользование Jetpack compose,сделал viewmodel с modelfactory для списка полученного из repository(Room). Все работает. Появился вопрос, а где прописать или как вообще использовать vewmodel для детальных записей. Например, с фрагментами и активити было все понятно, в create все описывали и все прекрасно работало. А здесь имея compose функции и отдельные классы(Screen), не совсем понятен подход с viemodel.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было передать в качестве параметра @Composable функции, ViewModel()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Если передаете в compose функцию viewModel в явном виде, то для использования фичи с Preview потребуется навесить на viewModel интерфейс и передавать его, а для Preview создавать заглушечный экземпляр